# jQuery Mobile List With Search

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a simple list with a search.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="true" data-iconpos="right">
```

My issue is that it loads fine and filters awesomely on my computer, but on my mobile device it makes safari lag really badly(locked up keyboard, horribly slow search).  I have an iPhone 4(iOS 5).

The list is pretty massive(5,000 or 6,000) li tags.

Does anyone know a good way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just gonna be too many DOM elements for a 1-GHz processor...

You will need to implement pagination or re-think your data-output to work well on mobile devices. Remember that even really nice mobile devices have the hardware of eight-year-old desktop computers.

Since you have so many list-items, how about doing a back-end search to kick things off? For instance, when the user types a search term, send the term to a server-side script that can then return a list of elements that match, then you could use the jQuery Mobile search filter widget to filter the list further.

Comment: thanks. I was considering something like this, but was hoping I was overlooking something simple.

Comment: @Kyle I have had this issue before and I implemented a server-side augmented solution where I only used the jQuery Mobile search filter after I had less than a set number of elements to search through (I think I used 50). It gave a great user experience...

Comment: Going to have to agree with jasper on this one - I would really look at  setting up a paging mechanism. That's just a crazy amount of JQM rendered markup.  Personally, I feel after 25 list items you should do paging, and then - if possible pre-fetch next 25 results - so at least the next page is ready to access after the initial list.

Comment: thanks everyone.  I added my own search algorithm to the field that calls a php script on every char entered.  this way the server was handling the brunt of the load and JQM just had to display results(instead of searching through that massive amount of DOM elements).  I was going to have the JQM data filter handle it after 50, but it was so fast and efficient, I didn't really see the point.  Anyway, thanks everyone for the help.